# How do I stop my program from outputting the same thing twice in a row?

Tags: javascript, debugging

So, I have created this HTML page with some JavaScript in it. And I have this button that outputs one out of six emojis. It worked fine and then I added some code to stop the program from outputting the same emoji twice in a row, but it doesn't make any difference and I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
function randEmoji()
        {
            var oldEmoji = emoji;
            var emojiList = [";)", ":D", "xD", ":O", ":X", ":P"];
            var emoji = emojiList[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojiList.length)];

            if (oldEmoji == emoji)
            {
                randEmoji();
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("emojiText").innerHTML = "Look how fun! ---> " + emoji + " <--- An emoji!";
                console.log(emoji);
            }
        }
```

I'm not very good at programming and have no idea what's causing this problem.

Please help me!

Comment: you have to declare your variables outside the function and set them inside. otherwise their values get reset in each function call

Comment: Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: You have not responded or marked any of the questions below as correct? If you are unaware of how to, select the best answer that solved your problem, then select the grey tick mark `✓` so it becomes green. This way, it means that the question has been resolved by that particular answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare your variables outside the function and set them inside. otherwise their values get reset in each function call.

Try this:

```js
var oldEmoji = '';
var emoji = '';
var emojiList = [";)", ":D", "xD", ":O", ":X", ":P"];

function randEmoji() {
    oldEmoji = emoji;
    emoji = emojiList[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojiList.length)];

    if (oldEmoji == emoji) {
        randEmoji();
    } else {
        console.log(emoji);
    }
}


var i = 0;
while (i < 20) {
    randEmoji();
    i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that any variables local to the function scope (meaning declared inside the function) are thrown away after the function completes its execution.  Thus, every time you run the function `emoji` and `oldEmoji` are reinstantiated from `undefined`

One solution would be to move one of those declarations to a parent scope, like so:

```js
var oldEmoji;

function randEmoji() {
    var emojiList = [";)", ":D"];
    var emoji = emojiList[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojiList.length)];
    
    if (oldEmoji == emoji) {
        randEmoji();
    } else {
        console.log(emoji);
        oldEmoji = emoji;
    }
}

randEmoji();
randEmoji();
randEmoji();
randEmoji();
randEmoji();
randEmoji();
randEmoji();
```

See here, we never actually get a repeat.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @full-stack answer, you could:

```
var oldEmoji = '';
      var emoji = '';
      var emojiList = [";)", ":D", "xD", ":O", ":X", ":P"];
      
    function randEmoji(){
       // remove old emoji first to avoid doing a recursive call
       var check = oldEmoji? emojiList.filter(e => e !== oldEmoji ) :  emojiList;
       var emoji = check[Math.floor(Math.random() * check.length)];
       oldEmoji = emoji
       document.getElementById("emojiText").innerHTML = "Look how fun! ---> " + emoji + " <--- An emoji!";
       console.log(emoji);
                    
  }
```